# The group of permutations on $\mathbf{Z}$ which preserve distance is generated by two elements of order 2.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finitely-generated

Let $G$ be the group of permutations on $\mathbf{Z}$ that preserve distance:

$$G = \{\sigma:\mathbf{Z}\to\mathbf{Z} : \, |\sigma(i)-\sigma(j)| = |i - j| \mathrm{\,for \, all \,} i,j\in\mathbf{Z} \}.$$

Show (by elementary methods) that $G$ is generated by two elements of order two.

I can do this for the dihedral group but that used geometric intuition that I don't have for the group of distance-preserving permutations on $\mathbf{Z}.$

Comment: Dunno but my first thought was to think of at least one example of such a map. How about fixing $0$ and swapping $n$ with $-n$? That works and it has order two.

Comment: @user4894 my understanding is that the identity has order 1, the typical definition being "the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $g^n = e$". And at any rate, my confusion is twofold since even if I had in hand two such operations I'm at a loss for how to show they generate all of $G$ since I don't know what $G$ really 'looks like'

Comment: Jim's answer is much more helpful :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two elements that might interest you are $\phi, \psi$ defined by $\phi(x) = -x$ and $\psi(x) = 1 - x$.  After confirming that $\phi, \psi \in G$ let $H = \langle\phi, \psi\rangle$, we want to show that $H = G$.

Start by figuring out what the product $\phi\psi$ is.  Use this to show that for $g \in G$ there is an element of the coset $Hg$ that fixes $0$.  Then show there's an element that fixes $0$ and $1$.  Then show that any element that fixes $0$ and $1$ is the identity.  Thus for all $g$, $1 \in Hg$ so $g \in H$.

Comment: Thanks! So then the picture for this is that we can click $\mathbf{Z}$ to the right $n$ times by application of $\psi^n$, to the left by $ \psi^{-n},$ and at any point stick a mirror at the $n$th place by $\psi^n \phi$?

Comment: $\psi$ has order $2$

Comment: thanks I see now :)